# SSH into Cluster Node and Run Py File

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to remote into a remote server and run a py file located on the machine.

`ssh node_url "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/ipython py_file.py"`

However, when I run this, the `ssh` completes, but immediately reverts back to my local machine then runs the command I issued and returns the following error due to no python existing:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/ipython", line 4, in <module>
    import IPython
ImportError: No module named Python`

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or how I could fix this? I've looked many places and no luck it seems.

Comment: So, "node_url" is the name of a remote server?

Comment: Yes, I just replaced the actual one with filler

Comment: And the file "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/ipython" exists on the local system too?

Comment: No that does not exist on the local system, which is why I think its failing. I would like that command to run on the remote server as it has ipython.

Answer (score 0):

The ssh succeeds and the command starts on system node_url, but fails while importing IPython with the message: "no module named Python".  There is a problem with the python installation on node_url.

Comment: If I was to run `/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/ipython py_file.py` on node_url, should it not work then? It will work if I manually ssh in and run it this way.

Comment: Easy to find out, but I think not.

Comment: I did test it. It works when I run it manually, which is why I don't think it is staying in the SSH connection. I guess I'll have to figure out a different approach.

Comment: If it works when you connect, then there is something in your profile that makes it tick.  Your profile isn't loaded when you don't login.  Do login with ssh, and run the "set" command. Quite possible one of the variables you see, is needed for IPython to run. A PATH variable perhaps.  Or IPYTHON_DIR ...